# Creating hive tables in S3 bucket using databricks

Tags: database, amazon-s3, hive, location, databricks

I want to set a global location for all the tables I create beforehand
Ex:

> Create table table name stored as parquet location 's3_bucket/db_name.db'

I am doing this in each table that I create,

I am looking for a setting like

> use database 's3_database_address'

So that I can eliminate the repeatative cmds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every managed table in Hive will by default be created in warehouse directory. You don't need to give location unless you want them to point to somewhere else than the default warehouse location.
Read this: http://www.devgrok.com/2018/12/using-s3-hive-metastore-with-emr.html?m=1

Comment: I am using databricks for creating the tables, and by default the tables are getting stored in databricks file storage and not in S3 bucket. I want to change this setting and store the table in S3 bucket without having to specify the S3 address in  location everytime I create the table

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a database](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-database.html) supports location argument.
If you then `USE DATABASE {}`, new tables will be created under the custom location of the database, not the default one.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But I'm facing one problem, the tables I'm creating are getting stored in previous folder on the address and not in the exact location.                       Ex. The address which I'm using while creating the database is S3://a/b/c. However, after I create the table using this database and check the location with command desc formatted it is in S3://a/b/c and not S3://a/b/c/new_database_name,